# Non-latin characters Alamofire 4.0 .GET Request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

So, I have an App in which you introduce a text in a `UITextField` and then it performs an Alamofire `.GET` request with text. Sometimes, that text is written in `Chinese, Korean, Japanese`... And Alamofire crashes, however if I type the URL in the browser with the Chinese characters it returns perfectly.

This is the URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&fields=items(id,snippet(title,channelTitle,thumbnails))&order=viewCount&q=不許你注定一人&type=video&maxResults=50&key=Whatever
```

As you can see it contains the Chinese text:

```
不許你注定一人
```

And this is the Alamofire .GET request:

```
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&fields=items(id,snippet(title,channelTitle,thumbnails))&order=viewCount&q=\(Text)&type=video&maxResults=50&key=Whatever"
        let nUrl = url.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
        Alamofire.request(nUrl, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to encode your url following [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) ?

```
extension String {
    func stringByAddingPercentEncodingForRFC3986() -> String? {
        let unreserved = "-._~/?"
        let allowed = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumeric()
        allowed.addCharacters(in: unreserved)
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed as CharacterSet)
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let nUrl = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingForRFC3986()
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks very much!